# Change JButton properties on mouse over

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, desktop-application

I am doing a calculator app with swing. I have changed the background color of JButton but when clicked its color changes to a blueish color. Can I set a color manually on mouse over and on click. like the windows 10 default calculator?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
buttonName.setFocusPainted(false);
```

This will get rid of the default border when you click on a button.
To make the button do stuff ie change it's background you can implement the MouseListener interface for it, but I think the best thing for you would be to read about event handling in swing :)
Here's a [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Swing/0600__Java_Swing_Event.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first detect mouse motion over the button using an [Mouse listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) .You can use an implemented version of it called the [MouseAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html)

```
 button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter()//To 
 detect mouse motion
  {
   @override
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m)//called when mouse 
enters first time into the button
  {
    button.setBackground(Color.blue);
   }

     @override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)//called when mouse is clicked[pressed and then released]
      {   
     button.setBackground(//whatever you want);
      }
     });
```

Note for mouse clicks you can just change the color inside your action listener